# create a list with strings in certain form in an automated way

Tags: python, string, list

I want to find an **easy** and an **automated** way in **python** for example using List comprehension to create a list containing strings in certain form.

For example I have this Input:

```
list1= [1 2 3 4 5]
list2= [10 20 30 40 50]
```

using list1 and list2 and adding the letters a and b the output would be like:

```
res= ['a:1 - b:10','a:2 - b:20','a:3 - b:30','a:3 - b:30','a:4 - b:40','a:5 - b:50']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use zip -

```
result = list([f'a:{a} - b:{b}' for a, b in zip(list1, list2)])
```

See here about [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) and about [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Comment: It'd be good if you could add a few links to documentation & break this down as it include list comprehensions too which the user may not be aware of

Comment: @jess - why didn't you mark this as the answer?

Comment: I just did know! I forgot it at that moment!